# Teradata and MySQL behave different in OVER() and Partition By () Clauses

Tags: mysql, teradata

I want to understand why the same query is producing different result in Teradata and My SQL.
I am trying to write a query for running total and each DB is giving me different solutions.

Below is the code:

```
CREATE TABLE runn_tot (p_id int, p_name varchar(10), price decimal(5,2));

insert into runn_tot values (1,'p1',34);
insert into runn_tot values (2,'p1',56);
insert into runn_tot values (3,'p1',65);
insert into runn_tot values (4,'p1',12);
insert into runn_tot values (5,'p1',34);
insert into runn_tot values (6,'p1',78);
insert into runn_tot values (7,'p1',23);
insert into runn_tot values (8,'p1',55);
insert into runn_tot values (9,'p1',34);
insert into runn_tot values (10,'p1',66);
```

The query which i'm using in Both MySQL and Teradata

```
select p_id, p_name, SUM(price) OVER ( partition by p_name order by p_id)  Running_Total
from runn_tot;
```

Results from MySQL:

```
+------+--------+---------------+
| p_id | p_name | Running_Total |
+------+--------+---------------+
|    1 | p1     |         34.00 |
|    2 | p1     |         90.00 |
|    3 | p1     |        155.00 |
|    4 | p1     |        167.00 |
|    5 | p1     |        201.00 |
|    6 | p1     |        279.00 |
|    7 | p1     |        302.00 |
|    8 | p1     |        357.00 |
|    9 | p1     |        391.00 |
|   10 | p1     |        457.00 |
+------+--------+---------------+
```

Results from Teradata:

```
1   p1  457.00
2   p1  457.00
3   p1  457.00
4   p1  457.00
5   p1  457.00
6   p1  457.00
7   p1  457.00
8   p1  457.00
9   p1  457.00
10  p1  457.00
```

I am trying to understand why MySQL is able to get the correct running total and teradata is not doing the window function correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Teradata implemented some Window Functions almost 20 years ago before they became part of Standard SQL 99 (using a proprietary syntax) and this behaviour is a kind of leftover.

In Standard SQL (and MySQL) when you specify `ORDER BY` the window defaults to `RANGE UNBOUNDED PECEDING`, which is not supported by Teradata, which defaults to `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING`. To  get the expected result you must add `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`, which is recommended over `RANGE` in other DBMSes, too (unless you actually need the result of a `RANGE`), because `ROWS` is way easier to calculate.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs.

Comment: The solution would be:                                                                                      
with data (p_id, p_name, price) as (
VALUES (1,'p1',34),
  (2,'p1',56),
  (3,'p1',65),
  (4,'p1',12),
  (5,'p1',34),
  (6,'p1',78),
  (7,'p1',23),
  (8,'p1',55),
  (9,'p1',34),
  (10,'p1',66)
)
SELECT p_id, p_name, sum(price) OVER (ORDER BY p_name ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM data
ORDER BY p_id